# java why does this give me notserializableexception

Tags: java, serialization

Why does this give me a notserializableexception ?

```
public class hData implements Serializable {
    String Symbol;
    double Position;

    public hData( String Symbol, double Position){

        this.Symbol = Symbol;
        this.Position = Position;
    }

}


  public List<hData> HData;
```

I serialize it like this:

```
public String objectToString(Serializable object) {
   String encoded = null;

   try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
    objectOutputStream.close();
    encoded = new String(Base64.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return encoded;
  }
```

And I call it:

```
String hd = objectToString((Serializable) HData);
```

Comment: Post the code that throws the exception, please.

Comment: Can you please post when does the exception happen with code samples?

Comment: List is java.util.List?

Comment: It doesn't. Show the full stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code. And respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter. Variables with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan It happens on the writeObject(object) line

Comment: Is your list one of the standard implementations like ArrayList or LinkedList? If not, then use new ArrayList(yourList) then it should be serializable.

Comment: @Patrick I just tried that - still same exception

Comment: Create an SSCCE reproducing the problem (you're not far from having it already), and paste the full code: from the package statement to the ending curly brace. My guess is that your List isn't really a regular ArrayList or LinkedList, but a custom implementation or a subList of another list, or that you're not using java.io.Serializable, but another Serializable interface.

Comment: And also post the *exception.* It names the class that isn't serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and it works. This is my code saved in hData.java. (BTW, Java classes are PascalCase by convention, So, HData is a better class name )

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

public class hData implements Serializable {
    String Symbol;
    double Position;

    public hData( String Symbol, double Position){

        this.Symbol = Symbol;
        this.Position = Position;
    }
    public static String objectToString(Serializable object) {
           String encoded = null;

           try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
            objectOutputStream.close();
            encoded = new String(Base64.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return encoded;
          }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<hData> HData = new ArrayList<hData>(); 
        HData.add(new hData("hi", 1.2));
        String hd = objectToString((Serializable) HData);
        System.out.print(hd);
    }
}
```